# Why doens't ColorAnimation work using TargetProperty="Fill"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, coloranimation

I am trying to make a slider control in WPF. So I have an ellipse to change its color to green when it's slided. I tried this code using `Storyboard.TargetProperty=Fill`

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ball" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" From="Red" To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
```

But it didn't work. I did some research and realized that it needs to be `Fill.Color`. Normally `Ellipse` has a `Fill` property to be filled. Why does it need the `Color` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fill` is a Brush type not a Color type. 
There are default converters in place that allow you to use simplified notations such as `Fill="Red"` in your XAML, but all that means is that you are setting `Fill` to a `SolidColorBrush` with a color of `Red`

A `ColorAnimation` as per its name will animate between Colors not Brushes, so you need to get to the Color property of the `Fill` (in your case fill is a SolidColorBrush which has a `Color` property).

As an additional example, if you were to set your `Fill` to a more complicated Brush such as a LinearGradientBrush, you can still manipulate the gradient in an `ColorAnimation` but the syntax becomes a lot more complex:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ball" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                From="Red" To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
```

Comment: Good explanation. WPF is so complex and i need more practice. Thanks for the answer.